# MikroTik RB750Gr3 - Slow WAN Speeds after Upgrade

Tags: router, performance, wan, hexadecimal, mikrotik

I am experiencing some issues with my MikroTik HEX RB750Gr3. I have never experiencing any issues with using the device until I updated my firmware for the first time. I was completing frequent OS updates but had missed the firmware updates as I was unaware they were disassociated. After completing this upgrade I have been experiencing an issue with my WAN speed.

My residential speeds are 1000/1000. But after the upgrade I have been getting a consistent 120/6. I thought that perhaps I created an issue with the upgrade so I completed a factory reset. This did not resolve the issue it remains the same.

This is with factory settings (auto configured). What am I missing in the newer editions of MikroTik that is impacting my speeds? I have verified that the queue on the default WAN port is set to ethernet-only. I have also verified that HW offloading is enabled on all four ports.

No matter what I change I have been unable to get the GIG speeds through the WAN. My LAN speeds are working correctly without any issue.

Any thoughts anyone has on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved through issues with the ISP provider. It was not in fact an issue with the router itself.